# Is it possible to replace this foreach loop with Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I have a foreach loop that I would like to replace with a Linq query, but I've not been able to figure out how to write the query.  Please see my example below and TIA.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class ExampleProgram
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            Device device = new Device();

            // The goal is to populate this list.
            var list1 = new List<IMemory>();

            // I would like to replace this loop with a Linq query
            foreach( MemoryBank memoryBank in device.MemoryBanks )
            {               
                list1.Add( memoryBank ); // add the memory bank

                foreach( MemoryBlock memoryBlock in memoryBank.MemoryBlocks )
                    list1.Add( memoryBlock ); // add the memory block
            }

            //var list2 = from memoryBank in device.MemoryBanks
            //            from memoryBlock in memoryBank.MemoryBlocks
            //            select ???;
        }
    }

    interface IMemory 
    {}

    public class Device
    { 
        public IList<MemoryBank> MemoryBanks { get; set; } 
    }

    public class MemoryBank : MemoryBlock, IMemory
    {
        public IList<MemoryBlock> MemoryBlocks { get; set; } 
    }

    public class MemoryBlock : IMemory 
    { }
}
```

Comment: Well, it could. But the moment you need to think more than 5 minutes while making LINQ query, then you know there is something wrong.

Comment: @Euphoric If you take that approach in programming, it will be very hard to expand your knowledge. Taking the 5 minutes to learn something here and there, will likely pay off in the end.

Comment: @jsmith: Its not about me. Its about other programmers. I would be confused for at least 5 minutes, if I saw queries people proposed. But original is crystal-clear right from the start.

Comment: @Euphoric I agree to an extent. But that is just because you are more comfortable with foreach loops. Someone comfortable with LINQ will know what those queries mean immediately. It likely depends on the developers he is working with. I agree that it shouldn't be used as a Golden Hammer however.

Comment: I am going to have to agree with jsmith here.  I learned something yesterday.  Yes, it took a good deal more than five minutes, but I'm better for it.  Once I understood Ani's answer, it makes as much sense to me as the nested foreach loops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
var list1 = device.MemoryBanks
                  .SelectMany(m => new[] { m }.Concat(m.MemoryBlocks))
                  .ToList();
```

Do note that this will create a `List<MemoryBlock>` rather than a `List<IMemory>` as in your sample. To make the list of the interface type, make the final call `ToList<IMemory>()`.

EDIT:

In .NET 3.5, in which the `IEnumerable<T>` interface is not covariant, you can do:

```
var list1 = device.MemoryBanks
                  .SelectMany(m => new IMemory[] { m }
                                       .Concat(m.MemoryBlocks.Cast<IMemory>()))
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: Will `Concat()` not complain because the implied type of `new [] {m}` is `IEnumerable<MemoryBank>` and not `IEnumerable<IMemory>` ?

Comment: @BrokenGlass: In .NET 4, the covariance of the interface means that an `IEnumerable<MemoryBank>` is also an `IEnumerable<MemoryBlock>`, which is what the first sample relies on. An `IEnumerable<MemoryBlock>` is in turn an `IEnumerable<IMemory>`, which you can rely on to call `ToList<IMemory>()`.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the additional explanation - so the type of the enumeration created by `Concat()` would be the first type in the interface hierarchy (going from the specific type up to `IMemory`) that both input enumerations share, correct? - covariance gets me every time (and +1)

Comment: @BrokenGlass: The type inference rules in C# are complicated (for me anyway)! I wouldn't dare make any sweeping statements. But in general, how you've summarized it for `Concat` isn't correct; the inferred type-argument should be one of the element-types of the sequence. So `new string[0].Concat(new FileInfo[0])` wouldn't work; you would have to explicitly specify the right type-argument: `new string[0].Concat<object>(new FileInfo[0])`. Also note that covariant conversions don't work when the type-argument of the constructed type is a value-type.

Comment: @BrokenGlass: My point essentially is that you must think of both the legality of the conversions and the inference of the type-arguments for the method-call. I too find this stuff complicated. I do think that most people not named Skeet/Lippert probably do too.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
list1 = device.MemoryBanks
              .Select( x=> x.MemoryBlocks.AsEnumerable<IMemory>().Concat(x))
              .SelectMany( x=>x)
              .ToList();
```