# Is it possible to use Linq to replace this Foreach loop

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to replace the foreach statement with a Linq command?

```
            string recipient = "recipients could not be defined"; 
            if (mail.To != null && mail.To.Count > 0) {
                var addresses = mail.To.Select(r => r.Address);
                foreach (string s in addresses) {
                    recipient += s + " ";
                }
            }
```

If I had ReSharper then I'm sure it would have come up with an appropriate suggestion but I don't. [This question uses Concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327782/is-it-possible-to-replace-this-foreach-loop-with-linq) and that feels like it should help but I'm not certain as to what object to use in the Concat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rather than using the Linq foreach (which is only available on `List<T>` unless you've written your own), you can do it backwards and avoid the string concatenation in the process:

```
recipient = string.Join(" ", mail.To.Select(r => r.Address));
```

This replaces your `var addresses...` onwards.

Comment: Beat me to it. :)  Note that this (possibly) also fixes a bug in the original code, which would result in `recipient` having a trailing space which I guess wasn't really wanted.

Comment: True! I remember the code I wrote before this either doing a Trim on the end, or manually trimming the last character from the StringBuilder that I'd used in the loop

Comment: If you use this, keep in mind you'll need the `mail.To != null` condition, but not the `mail.To.Count > 0`.

Comment: That's the ticket. Thank you. @Matthew Watson. I was only gathering information so wasn't too concerned about the extra trailing space but it's a bonus that this way fixes that issue as well.

Comment: I think he'll want to keep that condition because then the string will have the value of "...not defined" rather than being empty

Comment: Use `..&& mail.To.Any()` rather than Count()

Comment: The best approach. Every time one thinks of building a string from known parts `string.Join` and `string.Concat` should be the first things to come to mind. And it should be never `+=`- loops. `StringBuilder` at least.